# How to define protected field with public accessor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following situation:

```
data class Person(val name: string=""):Entity { }

open class Entity() { var id: Long=0 }
```

In this way, `id` is a public property, and the associated field is private (is not visible in Person class).

I'm working on an annotation processor and the annotation that I've defined works on fields. How can I define the property id as protected field with public accessor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set as a public variable and work with the scope of its setter, in this case, set the setter as protected using:

```
 var yourField: Any = /** initial value **/
    protected set
```

Read more about Visibility modifiers [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)